# Why is my promise chain failing?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, knex.js

I'm trying to seed a database using knex. With the help of a contributor, I've successfully seeded one table where I need to take several steps:

1. I need to pull id values from a couple of external tables so I can populate the seeding table's foreign key values.
2. Generate *n* records in the seeding table.
3. Populate the table.

As mentioned, I have this working for one table. Because I'm smarter than a roofing tack and have to do almost the exact same thing for another table, I just copied what was working in the first seed file, dropped it into the second seed file, made a couple of appropriate modifications (specifically, in the second table I only have to populate 1 foreign key value at this point) and...it doesn't work.

I'm at a loss. Surely there's some stupid little thing I'm missing in this code, but I can't find it. I'm trying to seed a `units` table that I have to populate with a `properties.id` value.

```
exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
    console.log('Seeding the %s table...', tableName);

    Promise.resolve([
        'properties',
    ])
    .map(function(table) {
        // Pull foreign key values (property_id)
        var ids = knex.select('id').from(table).pluck('id');

        // AT THIS POINT THE ids VARIABLE HAS A VALUE

        return ids;
    })
    .spread(function(properties) {
        // BUT I NEVER SEE THIS LOG PRINT
        console.log('SPREADING UNITS');
    });
};
```

What am I doing wrong? I've dropped `.catch()` and `.error()` into this thing, but nothing gets written to the log. Somehow I just never seem to drop into the `.spread(...)` method.

**UPDATE**

For whatever it's worth, this is the content of the `.map` method before it's returned...

```
{ client:
   { Formatter: { [Function: Formatter_MySQL] super_: [Function: Formatter] },
     Raw: { [Function: Raw_MySQL] super_: [Object] },
     Transaction: { [Function: Transaction_MySQL] super_: [Object] },
     QueryBuilder: { [Function: QueryBuilder_MySQL] super_: [Object] },
     QueryCompiler: { [Function: QueryCompiler_MySQL] super_: [Function: QueryCompiler] },
     migrationConfig: { tableName: 'knex_migration', directory: './migrations' },
     seedConfig: { directory: './seeds' },
     Runner: { [Function: Runner_MySQL] super_: [Function: Runner] },
     connectionSettings:
      { host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: '3306',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'realster',
        timezone: 'UTC',
        charset: 'utf8',
        debug: false },
     Pool: { [Function: Pool_MySQL] super_: [Function: Pool] },
     databaseName: 'realster',
     pool: { client: [Circular], config: [Object], genericPool: [Object] },
     _events: { start: [Function], query: [Function] },
     Seeder: { [Function: Seeder_MySQL] super_: [Function: Seeder] } },
  _single: { table: 'properties', pluck: 'id' },
  _statements:
   [ { grouping: 'columns', value: [Object] },
     { grouping: 'columns', type: 'pluck', value: 'id' } ],
  _errors: [],
  _joinFlag: 'inner',
  _boolFlag: 'and',
  _notFlag: false,
  and: [Circular],
  _method: 'pluck' }
```

Comment: You're using `.spread()` is this bluebird?

Comment: @SecondRikudo: `spread` is not a bluebird-only method. `.map` and `Promise.join` make it likely, though :-)

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, knex uses bluebird promises.

Comment: Yes, sorry. This is Bluebird bundled with Knex.

Comment: @RobWilkerson: I'm pretty sure you want `.then` instead of `.spread` there. Also, your usage of `Promise.join` misses the callback function.

Comment: @Bergi: I did change `.spread` to `.then`, but the result was the same. I never make it into that method. As for `.join`, I guess I'm not sure. It works fine on the other table, but I have to get there first. :-)

Comment: @RobWilkerson: What exactly is `ids`, did you log it? Is it a promise that never resolves? Some value with a `.then` method that doesn't do what it says? Another possibly explanation of the behaviour would be that *some* `.map` callbacks work but another one throws, but this seems unlikely given that your code iterates an one-item-array only (why?).

Comment: It's a promise. In the future I expect that 1 item to become more.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, @Bergi, I've updated the OP with the `ids` value before it's returned in `.map`. Still at a complete loss on this.

Comment: Please reduce your question's code to the bare minimum that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Done. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @RobWilkerson you didn't set `process.on("unhandledRejection"` or attach a `Promise.onPossiblyUnhandledRejection` handler right? In any case - try adding a `.catch(function(e){ console.log(e); })` _before_ the spread, does it log anything? Also, if you replace the `return ids` with just `return Promise.resolve()` does it work?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: There's no additional code in play. Adding `.catch()` before `.spread()` didn't change anything, nor did returning `Promise.resolve()` from `.map()`.

Comment: This _has_ to be something contextual since the `properties` table seeds just fine, right? According to the seed run output, the `properties` table is seeded before the `units` table and the `properties` table definitely has records when the run is complete. This seems so bizarre to me.

Comment: So if your map code is `.map(function(table) { return Promise.resolve([]); })` it doesn't log in the `.spread` o_0?

Comment: Okay, so yes. My bad. I took you very literally and used your original code as-is (`return Promise.resolve()`). As soon as I return `Promise.resolve([])`, I do get to `.spread()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `spread`, which is a method of `Promise`, in the result of a `map`.

The `map` probably produces an array, which doesn't have a `spread()` function.

Also, `spread` usually receives a callback with multiple arguments. If you need an array, simply use good old `then`.

In summary, I guess your code should look more like this:

```
var mapProperties = function(table) {
  return knex.select('id').from(table).pluck('id');
};

Promise.resolve([
  'properties'
])
.then(mapProperties)
.then(function(properties) {
  console.log(properties);
});
```

Comment: `map` is a promise method here which produces *a promise for* an array.

Comment: Nice. did not know about that.